# Slightly finer topology on a connected space

Tags: gn.general-topology

Let $(X,\tau)$ be a connected Hausdorff space.

Suppose $S\subseteq X$ is such that for every $U\in\tau$,  $$U\cap S\neq\varnothing \implies U\cap \overline S\setminus S\neq\varnothing.$$

Is it true that the topology generated by $\tau\cup \{S\}$ is also connected?

Comment: I think it is false because what if $X=\mathbb R$ in the usual topology and $S=\mathbb Q \cap (-\infty,0]$.

Comment: But isn't $(-\infty,0)\cup S$ open, with open complement?

Comment: but $S$ contains $0$

Comment: Yes, that is right, this counterexample seems totally fine.